# Regex to extract 1129 from '10px;> 1129'

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I want to extract the number `1129` from `10px;"> 1129` using Yahoo pipes regex.

I am using `(\d+)` to extract `1129` but what should I use to remove `10px;">`?

Comment: Are you trying to extract information from an HTML document using Regex?

Comment: @Gareth yes I am trying to extract info. from HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In: item.content
Replace: ^10px;">\s(\d+)$
With: $1
```

Comment: Thanks @Karolis it worked, but for some reason 'item.content' just got  vanished from Yahoo pipes 'V2' anyways I have added it manually. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If its always `10px;"> 1129` (or at least `xxx> YYYY` where YYY is your number) then I suppose your regex would be (in perl format):

> />\s(\d+)/

1129 will be in `$1`

Hope that helps. If no, please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve and what is your input.

Comment: Thaks a lot @RandomWhiteTrash, but it is not working its returning the same expresssion, here is the pipe http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d2a4df7265a0b820e0bc13c36c45e054